# How to add a new field to a form Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to add a new field to a form with Rails. Each field needs to have a dropdown of shipping options with the value of: shipping_option_id:

How do I do it with form?

Schema

```
 create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "sku"
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "shipping_option_id"
    t.bigint "product_region_id"
    t.index ["product_region_id"], name: "index_products_on_product_region_id"
    t.index ["shipping_option_id"], name: "index_products_on_shipping_option_id"
    t.index ["sku"], name: "index_products_on_sku", unique: true
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the helper `options_for_select` to add values from a given model in your `select_tag`

```
<%= select_tag 'shipping_option_id', options_for_select(@your_model.collect{ |o| [o.name, o.id] }) %>
```

Source: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag